# Using strings to identify label objects

Tags: c#

I am playing with windows forms in C#.  I have a window with quite a few labels on it:  label01, label02, label03, etc.  Each label has a button assigned to it: btn01, btn02, etc.

I would like to set `bnt01.visible = false` if its corresponding `label01.text == ""`.

I tried building an array to read in the labels, but was hoping to not have to enter in each label name.

So I was hoping to use a `for` loop to loop through the labels, find the blank ones, and hide its respective buttons:

```
string[] mysystems = new string[34]();  
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
    // Would like something similar to: mysystems[i]=label{0}.Text, i); 
    if(mysystems[i] != "") {}
    else
    {
        btn[i].visible = false; 
    }
}
```

I have looked at using reflection, but don't quite understand its concept.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `ButtonLabelPair` class:

```
internal class ButtonLabelPair
{
    internal Button AssociatedButton { get; private set; }
    internal Label AssociatedLabel { get; private set; }

    internal ButtonLabelPair(Button associatedButton, Label associatedLabel)
    {
        AssociatedButton = associatedButton;
        AssociatedLabel = associatedLabel;
    }
}
```

And then you could create a list of your pairs at some point on load:

```
var buttonLabelPairs = new List<ButtonLabelPair>();

buttonLabelPairs.AddRange(new ButtonLabelPair[] 
    {new ButtonLabelPair(btn01, label01), 
     new ButtonLabelPair(btn02, label02)});
```

Then you could do your loop like this:

```
foreach (var pair in buttonLabelPairs)
{
    pair.AssociatedButton.Visible =
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.AssociatedLabel.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called ButtonLabel

```
class ButtonLabel
{
    Label Label;
    Button Button;

    public ButtonLabel(Button Button, Label Label)
    {
        this.Label = Label;
        this.Button = Button;
    }

    public void HideIfEmpty()
    {
        if(Label.Text=="")
            Button.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

and then in your form create a List of ButtonLabel and do a foreach loop and call HideIfEmpty method like this :

```
List<ButtonLabel> List = new List<ButtonLabel>();
List.Add(new ButtonLabel(btn1,lbl1));
List.Add(new ButtonLabel(btn2,lbl2));
List.Add(new ButtonLabel(btn3,lbl3));
...
...

List.ForEach(I => 
{
    I.HideIfEmpty();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue the OP is addressing, which is "...but was hoping to not have to enter in each label name."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to do something of a similar nature

```
for (int i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
    string theControlNum = i < 1 ? "0" + i : i.ToString();
    if(this.Controls.Find($"label{theControlNum}").Text != "") {}
    else
    {
        this.Controls.Find($"btn{theControlNum}").visible = false; 
    }
}
```

As you can see the loop starts at 1 so that you don't need to use `i + 1` to get the control name as well as adding 0 to it if it is less than two digits long.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide a button control when a label is empty
try this:
in designer file:

```
Label lbl0 = new Label();
    lbl0.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(Lbl0_TextCanged);
```

in the source file of form:

```
public void Lbl0_TextCanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbl0.Text.Trim() == "") button1.Visible = false;

        }
```

I wrote 'Trim()' to delete the empty area in string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reflection, you can use Controls collection. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    var f = new Form {Text = "Sample Form"};
    // add 10 buttons and 10 labels like btn00, ... btn09 lbl00, ... lbl09
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button { Text = "Button" + i, 
            Name="btn" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'), 
            Top = i * 25, Left = 10, Width = 100 };
        var lbl = new Label { Text = i%2 == 0?"":"Visible", 
            Name="lbl" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'), 
            Top = i * 24, Left = 120};
        f.Controls.Add( btn );
        f.Controls.Add( lbl );
    }

    // make a button Visible = false if corrospending label is empty or null
    foreach (Label l in f.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where( l => Regex.IsMatch(l.Name, @"lbl\d{2}")))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Text))
        {
           f.Controls.OfType<Button>().Single(b => b.Name == l.Name.Replace("lbl","btn")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (form.Controls[$"label{i:D2}"].Text == "") {
        form.Controls[$"btn{i:D2}"].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

where `length` would be the number of label and button elements you've created, and `form` is the parent Form object.

**EDIT**: If you don't have C# 6.0, replace interpolated string with `string.Format`

```
string.Format("label{0:D2}", i)
```

Comment: label*01* not label1

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Corrected. Thanks

Comment: This is the way I wanted to go, but unfortunately I am running VS2013, and can't use interpolated strings yet (C#6/vs2015), as far as I know.

Comment: @Steve Replace it with `string.Format(...)`, what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary<Button, string>` where the key is button and the key's value is label's text. Then you can iterate dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Button, string>();
dictionary.Add(button1, label1.Text);
dictionary.Add(button2, label2.Text);
//  more pairs...
foreach(var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    if(dictionary[key] == "")
    {
        key.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to dump the  2 buttons for each label and just use selected text from the labels.  It wasn't that much more code and found some of it online:

```
private void btnShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Shutdown the highligted systems 
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            GetAllControl(this, list);
            DoShutdown(list);
        }

        private void btnRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Restart the highighted systems
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            GetAllControl(this, list);
            DoRestart(list);
        }

        private void DoRestart(List<Control> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in list)
            {
                if (control.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Aqua)
                {
                    restart m = new restart();
                    m.restartwin(control.Text);

                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Restart sent!", "Restart", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void DoShutdown(List<Control> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in list)
            {
                if (control.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Aqua)
                {
                    powerApp m = new powerApp();
                    m.poweroffwin(control.Text);

                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Shutdown sent!", "Shutdown", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }  


        private void GetAllControl(Control c, List<Control> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);

                if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    GetAllControl(control, list);
                }

            }
        }
```

To all, thank you for the fast responses and help, I learned a lot of different ideas for down the road.